# What tools for server side application performance testing you suggest?

Tags: java, performance, testing

What tools for server side application performance testing you suggest? Have an application server and need to test it performance. Not sure issue is server side. Need to investigate.
NB:Better to have convenient UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is a powerful tool for performance testing web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Java Performance Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/java/profiler/index.html) to launch Apache (or other Java web server), the start your app in the web browser.